# Redis pod failing

Tags: kubernetes, redis, minikube

I have redis DB setup running on my minikube cluster. I have shutdown my minikube and started after 3 days and I can see my redis pod is failing to come up with below error from pod log

```
Bad file format reading the append only file: make a backup of your AOF file, then use ./redis-check-aof --fix <filename>.
```

Below is my Stateful Set yaml file for redis master deployed via a helm chart

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-redis
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: master
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
    helm.sh/chart: redis-14.8.11
  name: test-redis-master
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "191902"
  uid: 3a4e541f-154f-4c54-a379-63974d90089e
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
      app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
  serviceName: test-redis-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/configmap: dd1f90e0231e5f9ebd1f3f687d534d9ec53df571cba9c23274b749c01e5bc2bb
        checksum/health: xxxxx
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: master
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
        helm.sh/chart: redis-14.8.11
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app.kubernetes.io/component: master
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
                  app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
              namespaces:
              - tyk
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            weight: 1
      containers:
      - args:
        - -c
        - /opt/bitnami/scripts/start-scripts/start-master.sh
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        env:
        - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
          value: "false"
        - name: REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE
          value: master
        - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "no"
        - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: redis-password
              name: test-redis
        - name: REDIS_TLS_ENABLED
          value: "no"
        - name: REDIS_PORT
          value: "6379"
        image: docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.5-debian-10-r11
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - /health/ping_liveness_local.sh 5
          failureThreshold: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 6
        name: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - /health/ping_readiness_local.sh 1
          failureThreshold: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1001
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/bitnami/scripts/start-scripts
          name: start-scripts
        - mountPath: /health
          name: health
        - mountPath: /data
          name: redis-data
        - mountPath: /opt/bitnami/redis/mounted-etc
          name: config
        - mountPath: /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/
          name: redis-tmp-conf
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      serviceAccount: test-redis
      serviceAccountName: test-redis
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 493
          name: test-redis-scripts
        name: start-scripts
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 493
          name: test-redis-health
        name: health
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: test-redis-configuration
        name: config
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: redis-tmp-conf
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: master
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
        app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
      name: redis-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 8Gi
      volumeMode: Filesystem
    status:
      phase: Pending
```

Please let me know your suggestions on how can I fix this.

Comment: Could you add your Pod / Deployment configuration ?

Comment: Thanks @tmarwen for the help. I have added my STS yaml to the question which is deployed via helm chart.

Comment: Please provide your helm install options, additional configuration used for redis, `kubectl describe pod <your redis pod>` with all useful information from events section - looks like problem with config file validation during pod startup.

Comment: Also add your cluster version...

Comment: [@Chandra Sekar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6572074/chandra-sekar) Any progress with your issue?

Comment: Hey @Mark I have deleted the entire redis db and recreated a fresh one as I couldn't able to recover from this

Comment: did you try repair `appendonly.aof` file using helper pod `redis-client` as in the example provided below?

Answer (score 12):

I am not an Redis expert but from what I can see:

```
kubectl describe pod red3-redis-master-0
...
Bad file format reading the append only file: make a backup of your AOF file, then use ./redis-check-aof --fix <filename>
...
```

Means that your appendonly.aof file was corrupted with invalid byte sequences in the middle.

How we can proceed if redis-master is not working?:

- Verify `pvc` attached to the `redis-master-pod`:

```
kubectl get pvc

NAME                               STATUS   VOLUME                                    
redis-data-red3-redis-master-0     Bound    pvc-cf59a0b2-a3ee-4f7f-9f07-8f4922518359
```

- Create new `redis-client pod` wit the same `pvc` `redis-data-red3-redis-master-0`:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis-client
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: redis-data-red3-redis-master-0
  containers:
    - name: redis
      image: docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.3-debian-10-r0
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args: ["-c", "sleep infinity"]
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/tmp"
          name: data
EOF
```

- Backup your files:

```
kubectl cp redis-client:/tmp .
```

- Repair appendonly.aof file:

```
kubectl exec -it redis-client -- /bin/bash

cd /tmp

# make copy of appendonly.aof file:
cp appendonly.aof appendonly.aofbackup

# verify appendonly.aof file:
redis-check-aof appendonly.aof

...
0x              38: Expected prefix '*', got: '"'
AOF analyzed: size=62, ok_up_to=56, ok_up_to_line=13, diff=6
AOF is not valid. Use the --fix option to try fixing it.
...

# repair appendonly.aof file:
redis-check-aof --fix appendonly.aof

# compare files using diff:
diff appendonly.aof appendonly.aofbackup
```

Note:

> [As per docs](https://redis.io/topics/persistence):
>
> **The best thing to do is** to **run the redis-check-aof utility, initially without the --fix option**, then understand the problem, jump at the given offset in the file, **and see if it is possible to manually repair the file**: the AOF uses the same format of the Redis protocol and is quite simple to fix manually. **Otherwise it is possible to let the utility fix the file** for us, **but in that case all the AOF portion from the invalid part to the end of the file may be discarded**, **leading to a massive amount of data loss if the corruption happened to be in the initial part of the file**.

In addition as described in the comments by [@Miffa Young](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889647/redis-pod-failing/68902852#comment121826920_68902852) you can verify where your data is stored using `k8s.io/minikube-hostpath provisioner`:

```
kubectl get pv 
...
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                      
pvc-cf59a0b2-a3ee-4f7f-9f07-8f4922518359   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/redis-data-red3-redis-master-0     
...

kubectl describe pv pvc-cf59a0b2-a3ee-4f7f-9f07-8f4922518359
...
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /tmp/hostpath-provisioner/default/redis-data-red3-redis-master-0
...
```

Your redis instance is failing down because your `appendonly.aof` is malformed and stored permanently under this location.

You can ssh into your vm:

```
minikube -p redis ssh 
cd /tmp/hostpath-provisioner/default/redis-data-red3-redis-master-0
# from there you can backup/repair/remove your files:
```

Another solution is to install this chart using new name in this case new set of  pv,pvc for redis StatefulSets will be created.

Answer (score 1):

- I think  your  redis  is  not  quit Gracefully , so  the AOF file is in a bad format  [What is AOF](https://redis.io/topics/persistence)
- you should repair aof file using a initcontainer by command  (./redis-check-aof --fix .)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-redis
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: master
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
    helm.sh/chart: redis-14.8.11
  name: test-redis-master
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "191902"
  uid: 3a4e541f-154f-4c54-a379-63974d90089e
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
      app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
  serviceName: test-redis-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/configmap: dd1f90e0231e5f9ebd1f3f687d534d9ec53df571cba9c23274b749c01e5bc2bb
        checksum/health: xxxxx
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: master
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
        helm.sh/chart: redis-14.8.11
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app.kubernetes.io/component: master
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
                  app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
              namespaces:
              - tyk
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            weight: 1
      initContainers:
      - name: repair-redis
        image: docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.5-debian-10-r11
        command: ['sh', '-c', "redis-check-aof --fix  /data/appendonly.aof"]
      containers:
      - args:
        - -c
        - /opt/bitnami/scripts/start-scripts/start-master.sh
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        env:
        - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
          value: "false"
        - name: REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE
          value: master
        - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "no"
        - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: redis-password
              name: test-redis
        - name: REDIS_TLS_ENABLED
          value: "no"
        - name: REDIS_PORT
          value: "6379"
        image: docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.5-debian-10-r11
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - /health/ping_liveness_local.sh 5
          failureThreshold: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 6
        name: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - /health/ping_readiness_local.sh 1
          failureThreshold: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1001
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/bitnami/scripts/start-scripts
          name: start-scripts
        - mountPath: /health
          name: health
        - mountPath: /data
          name: redis-data
        - mountPath: /opt/bitnami/redis/mounted-etc
          name: config
        - mountPath: /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/
          name: redis-tmp-conf
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      serviceAccount: test-redis
      serviceAccountName: test-redis
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 493
          name: test-redis-scripts
        name: start-scripts
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 493
          name: test-redis-health
        name: health
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: test-redis-configuration
        name: config
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: redis-tmp-conf
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: master
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-redis
        app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
      name: redis-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 8Gi
      volumeMode: Filesystem
```

Comment: I am getting an error  "Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec.template.spec): unknown field "initcontainers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec" when I add init containers field in the sts manifest

Comment: sorry   ， It‘s   initContainers. I fixed this typo.

Comment: After adding initContainers it is not starting saying Init:Error :(

Comment: kubectl    logs    your_podname    -n   your_amespace     init  : check  initcontainer logs

Comment: @[Chandra Sekar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6572074/chandra-sekar) did you try to fix `appendonly.aof` file with `redis-check-aof` bin?

Comment: If   data  in  redis  is  not  important and discardable，  you  can   delete  this workload， and  recreate  it.

Comment: @Mark how to do that when redis pod is not even starting

Comment: @MiffaYoung I even deleted and recreated STS still it is failing with same error

Comment: You must delete the pvc  mounted by  redis； Though you  recreate the redis， the redis pvc（data  dir） is  not  deleted， so  the bad aof  file  is  still  here；